# How to click the next link in google search results?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to move onto the next-page of the google search results using Selenium; something which can achieved by clicking Next in the browser when done manually. Below is the snippet

```
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_name("q")
inputElement.send_keys('python' + Keys.RETURN)
```

Any pointers or snippets would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, i am not clear, in google search you are entering something and then what trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straightforward: *locate the link by it's text*:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()
```

Demo:

```
>>> driver.current_url
u'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=python'
>>> driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()
>>> driver.current_url
u'https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=python&start=10'
```

Comment: Its throwing up error. selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Next"}

Comment: @Ram: are you using the Google in english? :) I know that it is a dump question, so sorry for that in advance :)

Comment: @Manu well, I've actually tested it before posting :)