# Google search next pages using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate the clicking of the next page in google search, after I must have gone into the links in the 1st and 2nd search page.

I've so far been able to do the following:

1. Spin up the chrome browser
2. Go to the Google webpage
3. Type in the search words
4. Click on the search icon
5. Go into the links on the 1st and 2nd google page

See my code below:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from parsel import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#path to the chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users\my_path/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.gooogle.com')

#locate search form by name
search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

#Input search words
search_query.send_keys('X-Men')

#Simulate return key
search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

Xmen_urls = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')

for page in range(0,3):
    Xmen_urls = [url.text for url in Xmen_urls]

    #loop to iterate through all links in the google search query
    for Xmen_url in Xmen_urls:
         driver.get(Xmen_url)
         sel = Selector(text = driver.page_source)

    #Go back to google search
    driver.get('https://www.gooogle.com') 

    #locate search form by name
    search_query = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

    #Input search words
    search_query.send_keys('X-Men')

    #Simulate return key
    search_query.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    #find next page icon in Google search
    Next_Google_page = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next").click()

    page += 1
```

When I'm done collecting the links on the '2nd' search page, how do I tell the algorithm to start from the '2nd' search page and not the 1st search page (this will enable me go into >2 pages).

I know it's a 'for loop' and syntax re-arranging I'm missing somewhere but my brain is frozen at this point.

I saw this page: [How to click the next link in google search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040973/how-to-click-the-next-link-in-google-search-results) but it only helps if I'm not navigating away from the google search page

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens after you've collected the links on the 2nd? When you click 'Next' you get an error? Sorry if I don't understand, it seems pretty straightforward to navigate to the next pages...

Comment: Also, use this to click the Next button: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'span') and contains(text(), 'Next')]")

Comment: @Alichino, did an update to the code, the answer to your question is that on collecting the links from the next page, my code currently goes back again to the 1st search page so clicking on next  just takes me to the 2nd page and not the 3rd page as I want.

Comment: Why do you go back to the google search and search again rather than collect 1st page, click Next, collect page 2 and so on...? EDIT: NEVERMIND, I get it. One moment pls

Comment: @Alichino, that's my question! how do I store the web page of page 2 so by the time I click next it takes me to page 3. Remember I'd left the google search page to look at links in page 2, so I now need to return to page 2 after looking at the links on page 2 and go to page 3, get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways I can see:

Open each X-Men url in a separate window using window_handles, collect page_source, close the window and switch back to the original window.

```
driver.execute_script("window.open(X-Men_url, 'new_window')")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
sel = Selector(text = driver.page_source)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

The code above may not work exactly, but something to that effect.

The other way is to simulate a number of clicks on NEXT at the beginning of your FOR loop using a loop:

```
a = 0;
while a <= page:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(local-name(), 'span') and contains(text(), 'Next')]").click()
    a = a+1
```

Comment: Thanks Alichino, the 2nd option worked well for me (with some tinkering though). I knew it was some loop solution but I froze out... thanks again.

Comment: Hehe looking at it now, it will click NEXT even if page == 0. 'a' should have been declared as a = 1 (sorry for the semicolon, I've been working in Java the last 3 months).